# How to process more complex tuplets in Haskell?

Tags: string, haskell

Basicly this piece of code works:

```
toFullName :: Student -> String
toFullName (Student firstName lastName _) = firstName ++ " " ++ lastName

namesList :: [Student] -> [String]
namesList students = map toFullName students
```

And this below doesn't

```
toRaport :: (Int, Student) -> String
toRaport (num, Student firstName lastName age) = num ++ ". student: " ++ lastName ++ " " ++ firstName ++ ". wiek: " ++ age ++ "\n" 

raportList :: [(Int,Student)] -> [String]
raportList students = map toRaport students
```

Eventhough they are very similar and i just don't know how to process more complex tuplets in Haskell.

Comment: Please share the compiler error.

Comment: Since `num` is an `Int`, you can not write `num ++ ...`. You should use `show`, so `show num ++ ". student: " ++ ...`.

Comment: You'd have the exact same problem with `data Student = Student Int String`. This isn't about tuples.

Comment: Well I was too much focused on this, that maybe syntax must be different, im just very inexprienced in Haskell and need to do short task, but I don't know enough about the basics of this language.

Comment: I'm sure there'd be fewer downvotes if you'd included the compiler error in full (as we're supposed to do, when asking questions on SO). you can *edit* your post.

Comment: I don't care much about this, SO comments helped me solved my problem quite fast and compiler error was not needed.

Answer (score 0):

I added show where needed and now it's like this:

```
    indexList listToProcess
=> [(1,Student {firstName = "Alicja", lastName = "Akla", age = 21}),(2,Student {firstName = "Batrek", lastName = "Bodo", age = 20}),(3,Student {firstName = "Celina", lastName = "Czyzyk", age = 21}),(4,Student {firstName = "Damian", lastName = "Dab", age = 22}),(5,Student {firstName = "Eustachy", lastName = "Elo", age = 20})]
   a = indexList listToProcess
   raportList a
=> ["1. student: Akla Alicja. wiek: 21\n","2. student: Bodo Batrek. wiek: 20\n","3. student: Czyzyk Celina. wiek: 21\n","4. student: Dab Damian. wiek: 22\n","5. student: Elo Eustachy. wiek: 20\n"]
```

So it works but I would like it to be in different format, instead of [(Int,Student)] -> [String] i need to actually changed it to [(Int,Student)] -> String.
So that those \n actually format whole thing correctly.

Comment: Take a look at `unlines :: [String] -> String`.

Comment: Oh right, but how to change \n into actually new line?

Comment: you can *print* the string with `putStrLn`. If it returns a string, `ghci` will show it as a string *literal* (so as if you would write the string in a Haskell program).

Comment: oh right, thats solves it, I only need another function that combines those opertations.

Comment: That's a separate question. Start a new post.

Comment: Chill out, I hadn't really asked a question in my previous comment, as I can handle it myself.